# AppCompatSpinner.setSelection does not work second time

Tags: android, android-spinner

I placed an AppCompatSpinner on a dialogue. Setting selection with setSelection() works first time, but when the dialogue is shown again, setSelection() does not work. Why?

For example, in the following example, if I press Homer button first, the spinner shows Homer, but then if I press Marge button, the spinner still shows Homer, even though I see the debug message "Setting to marge".

If I press Marge first, then the spinner always shows Marge, even though I press Homer later.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button homer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.homer);
        homer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("name", "homer");
                MyDialogue dlg = MyDialogue.getInstance(args);
                dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), dlg.getClass().getName());
            }
        });

        Button marge = (Button)findViewById(R.id.marge);
        marge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("name", "marge");
                MyDialogue dlg = MyDialogue.getInstance(args);
                dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), dlg.getClass().getName());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyDialogue.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyDialogue extends AppCompatDialogFragment
{
    static MyDialogue instance;

    public static MyDialogue getInstance(Bundle args)
    {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new MyDialogue();
        instance.setArguments(args);
        return instance;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogue, container, false);
        AppCompatSpinner family = (AppCompatSpinner) v.findViewById(R.id.family);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        final String name = args.getString("name");

        if(name.equals("homer"))
        {
            Log.d("spin", "Setting to homer");
            family.setSelection(0);
        }
        else if(name.equals("marge"))
        {
            Log.d("spin", "Setting to marge");
            family.setSelection(1);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("spin", "Setting to bart");
            family.setSelection(2);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="Homer"
        android:id="@+id/homer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Marge"
        android:id="@+id/marge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

dialogue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:entries="@array/list_items"
        android:id="@+id/family"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Test2</string>
    <string-array name="list_items">
        <item>Homer</item>
        <item>Marge</item>
        <item>Bart</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `setSelection` call to `onResume` like this:

```
@Override 
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  Bundle args = getArguments();
  final String name = args.getString("name", "");

  if (name.equals("homer")) {
    Log.d("spin", "Setting to homer");
    family.setSelection(0);
  } else if (name.equals("marge")) {
    Log.d("spin", "Setting to marge");
    family.setSelection(1);
  } else {
    Log.d("spin", "Setting to bart");
    family.setSelection(2);
  }
}
```

Whenever I've worked with `setSelection` it has always been flakey. My guess is that since you're setting `android:entries` instead of creating the adapter yourself, it may be the cause of the adapter being reset after your `setSelection` calls, causing it to reset to position 0 (Homer in this case). Moving the selection into the `onResume` will fix this by waiting until all initialization has completed.

Comment: I moved the code from onCreateView to onResume, and now the problem is gone. This is weird because, setting other things like the text of a TextView worked on onCreateView. By the way, it was not always reset to 0, it just kept the index firstly set. For example, if I set Marge first (position 1), it kept showing Marge. Is it a better practice to create adapter manually than using entries? I only used entries because I did not want to use hard-coded strings for items in case of internationalisation.